# Google Maps API sensor not setting to true or false

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false' is my error. Below is my script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="<%=GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY %>"&sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: remove `"` around sensor...

Comment: Is this ASP? Either ways, it's producing something like `src="...?key="KEY_HERE"&sensor=true"`, which obviously is not a great url :) Check out the final result, I think Anto is correct.